# Как узнать объект вызвавший событие DropDown

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-n-drop

Суть в том, что у меня 18 изображений. Первые 9 - сетка (1-9), другие 9 - кусочки одного изображения (10-18).  Мне надо, чтобы перетаскиваемый кусок изображения вставал в то же положение, что и, сетка на которую дропнулось изображение (игра пазл). Я знаю, что есть sender в событии dropdown сетки (первых 9 изображений). Но здесь я не понимаю одного...
 Почему он возвращает имя объекта на которое падает изображение, а не имя падающего изображения, вызывает же событие dragdrop именно падающее изображение, а не принимающее. В Delphi,  помимо sender,  была ещё одна переменная Source, которая как раз показывала тот объект, который активирует событие. Может быть есть такой же в C#?

```
private void pictureBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        /* if (sender is PictureBox)
         {
             pictureBox10.Location = (sender as PictureBox).Location;
             (sender as PictureBox).Location = 
         }
        */
        PictureBox picture = e.Data.GetData(typeof(PictureBox)) as PictureBox;


            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(picture));
    }
```

Я пытался сделать проверку на то, что получу, но в итоге выводится пустой MessageBox

Comment: `DragEventArgs.Data` смотрели?

Comment: Как это можно реализовать ? К примеру, мне по нему нужно сделать проверку, что это pictureBox10 и именно он drop - нулся на pictureBox1. Можно, пожалуйста, пример.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос код на onMouseDown(), где Вы начинаете процедуру перетаскивания

Comment: По моему в с# PictureBox и Image далеко не одно и то же. По тому, что Вы написали в комментариях, к моему вопросу Вы работаете c Image, а не PictureBox. Поэтому естественно у Вас возникли проблемы. Дабы не было гадания на кофейной гуще - в вопрос нужно добавить всю необходимую информацию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надеюсь, что мой пример (там источник данных TreeView ) даст Вам подсказку (с PictureBox все точно также по этой схеме)

```
     private void lstBxRegionsForSearch_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
     {
         //Анализируем, что принесли на мыше
         TreeNode node = e.Data.GetData(typeof(TreeNode)) as TreeNode;
         if (node == null) return;

         //Дальше Ваши действия с объектом node (у Вас это будет конкретный pictureBox 
         .......
     }

     lstBxRegionsForSearch - это приемник, который обрабатывает событие DragDrop
```

Comment: Блин, я глупенький (Ну прям очень).
Компонент lstBxRegionsForSearch я почему-то не нашёл. 
Как я понял, то проверку DragDrop можно сделать и на PictureBox (1 - 9), если да, то я попытался это сделать, но ничего не получилось.

Comment: @Criptonium, если пример помог, то хорошо бы принять ответ. Джентльмены находят, что положительная реакция на полезный ответ  способствует, желанию помогать людям и делает мир лучше

Comment: @Criptonium, пока Вам писал сообщение, Вы добавили новую информацию, ее хорошо бы добавить в текст вопроса.

Comment: @Criptonium, Потрачу еще на Вас время - как Вы начинаете процедуру DragDrop - конкретно, где у Вас вызывается doDragDrop() и что Вы ему передаете в качестве аргументов?

Comment: Да, конечно, я плюсану  хорошие ответы, но только после того, как вопрос будет решён, негоже как-то закрывать не решённый (для меня) вопрос.

Comment: @Criptonium "..Компонент lstBxRegionsForSearch я не нашел..." - естественно, у Вас не было кода и я использовал свой действующий код, надеюсь Вы понимаете, что lstBxRegionsForSearch в Вашем случае pictureBox1 :)

Comment: @Criptonium, посмотрите в отладчике, что Вы получаете после исполнения этой строки "PictureBox picture = e.Data.GetData(typeof(PictureBox)) as PictureBox;"

Comment: DragDrop вызывается на pictureBox (Код я перекинул в вопрос) (Это единственное место, где у меня вызывается DragDrop (В будущем он будет и в других pictureBox'ax 1-9)) Так же, написан одно и то же событие DragEnter
`e.Effect = e.AllowedEffect;` 
(На изображениях 1 - 9)
И событие  MouseDown
`pictureBox10.DoDragDrop(pictureBox10.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);`
(На изображениях 10-18)

Comment: picture была null. У неё постоянно значение null

Comment: "...picture была null..." - программа сделала все правильно, потому что Вы написали "pictureBox10.DoDragDrop(pictureBox10.Image, DragDropEffects.Move);". Соответственно должно быть в приемной части " PictureBox picture = e.Data.GetData(typeof(PictureBox)) as Image;"  :))

Comment: Если Вы хотите получить PictureBox, то нужно "pictureBox10.DoDragDrop(pictureBox10, DragDropEffects.Move);"

Comment: Я изменил. Теперь в MessageBox вписывается: "System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox, SizeMode: Normal". Уже доволен, что хотя бы работает, но нужно, чтобы я получал имя переменной (PictureBox(10-18))

Comment: @Criptonium, у pictureBox есть поля по моему Name, вместо "...Convert.ToString(picture)..." сделайте просто "...picture.Name..." и жизнь наладиться

Comment: Воу, ура! Всё получилось! Спасибо огромное... Ну и намучились вы со мной :D Зато, вроде, всё понял :3 Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Помочь - это не мученья - это всегда хорошо :). Но все было бы намного быстрее, если бы Вы сразу всю информацию, которую я вытаскивал из Вас в комментариях, была бы сразу в тексте вопроса.